# Calculate distance between objects with xy coordinates as attributes

Tags: python, coordinates, distance

Say we have two types of objects, patients and hospitals:

```
import random

class Patient:
    def __init__(self):
        x = random.randint(0,100)
        y = random.randint(0,100)

class Hospital:
    def __init__(self):
        x = random.randint(0,100)
        y = random.randint(0,100)
```

Say we had lists of 25 patients and 5 hospitals.

```
PatientList = []

for p in range(25):
    PatientList.append(Patient())

HospitalList = []

for p in range(5):
    HospitalList.append(Hospital())
```

The goal is to use the XY coordinates belonging to each object to find the closest hospital to the individual patient. Ideally, we would also be able to rank the hospitals in order of distance, or at least be able to find the second closest, third closest, etc. after the closest hospital is found.

Comment: Both `Patient` and `Hospital` should inherit from a common `Position` class that has a `distance_to(self, other: Position) -> float` method. That would be much cleaner than having explicit calculations like in the current two answers proposed.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to assign your fields:

```py
class Patient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(0,100) # use self.x
        self.y = random.randint(0,100)

class Hospital:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(0,100)
        self.y = random.randint(0,100)
```

You could use a [min heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) to get the nearest n hospitals efficiently

```py
import heapq
def closest_hospitals(patient, hospitals, n):
    heap = []
    for h in hospitals:
        # since we are not really concerned with the distance but closeness
        # we only need to compare dist^2
        dist = (patient.x - h.x)**2 + (patient.y - h.y)**2
        heap.append((dist, hospital))) 

    heapq.heapify(heap) # now we have a valid heap (this takes O(N=100))

    # then return n-closest
    closest = heapq.nsmallest(n, heap) #you choose n
    
    return closest
```

This has complexity `O(H + n * lg(H))` where H is the number of the number of hospitals and n in the number of nearest hospitals you (compared to sorting everything which would take `O(H lg H)`.

Comment: Finding the closest hospital (minimum) does not require sorting. It is a simple `O(H)` operation. Finding the closest hospital for each patient is `O(n*H)`.

Comment: @PierreD Yes that's true, but they do ask for finding k-closest hospitals to a patient  as an extension

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import random


class Patient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(0, 100)  # you need to use self.x to access this variable
        self.y = random.randint(0, 100)


class Hospital:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(0, 100)
        self.y = random.randint(0, 100)


PatientList = []

for p in range(25):
    PatientList.append(Patient())

HospitalList = []

for p in range(5):
    HospitalList.append(Hospital())

# convert data to numpy arrays
PatientArray = np.array([[p.x, p.y] for p in PatientList])
HospitalArray = np.array([[p.x, p.y] for p in HospitalList])
PatientArray = PatientArray[:, np.newaxis]  # add an extra dimension

differences = PatientArray - HospitalArray  # broadcast
distances = np.linalg.norm(differences, axis=2)  # find euclidean distance
proximity_matrix = np.argsort(distances, axis=1)  # sort by proximity between patients and hospitals
PatientDict = {}  # create a dictionary with patients as keys and list of hospitals (ordered by proximity) as values

# iterate over the proximity matrix and the patient list simultaneously
for hospitals_proximity, patient in zip(proximity_matrix, PatientList):
    sorted_hospitals = [HospitalList[i] for i in hospitals_proximity]
    PatientDict[patient] = sorted_hospitals
```

now `PatientDict` contains all patients as keys and hospital sorted by proximity as values

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: use `KDTree` (method 3 below). It will find the closest hospital among 6,200 hospitals (≈number of hospitals in the US) for 20 million patients in under 10 seconds.  And the top 10 closest hospitals for the same 20 million patients in under 30 seconds.

Let `n` be the number of patients and `m` the number of hospitals. We show below several ways to find the closest hospital for each patient:

1. Using direct calculation done by class methods (`O(n * m)` in Python).
2. Using `numpy` on arrays built for hospitals and patients (still `O(n * m)`, but in C/C++).
3. Using [`KDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) (`O(n log m)` on average). That approach directly lets us look up the top `k` hospitals as well.

But first, let's add some power to your classes:

```py
import random
import math

class Position:
    def __init__(self, x=None, y=None):
        self.x = random.randint(0, 100) if x is None else x
        self.y = random.randint(0, 100) if y is None else y

    def as_tuple(self):
        return self.x, self.y

    def dist(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Position):
            raise ValueError(f"don't know how to compute distance to {type(other)}")
        return math.sqrt((self.x - other.x)**2 + (self.y - other.y)**2)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__} at {self.as_tuple()}'
        
class Patient(Position):
    pass

class Hospital(Position):
    pass
```

Now:

```py
random.seed(0)  # reproducible test
PatientList = [Patient() for _ in range(25)]
HospitalList = [Hospital() for _ in range(5)]

>>> HospitalList
[Hospital at (92, 51),
 Hospital at (90, 100),
 Hospital at (85, 80),
 Hospital at (0, 78),
 Hospital at (63, 42)]
```

#### Closest hospital for each patient, in Python

```py
# compute all n * m distances:
alldist = [[h.dist(p) for h in HospitalList] for p in PatientList]

# find the index of the closest hospital for each patient:
h_i = [min(range(len(dists)), key=lambda i: dists[i]) for dists in alldist]

>>> h_i
[2, 4, 3, 4, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 4, 2, 4, 4, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3]


# for example, all hospital distances for patient 0:
>>> alldist[0]
[62.96824596572466,
 41.10960958218893,
 39.81205847478876,
 52.55473337388365,
 56.753854494650845]

# and, indeed:
>>> alldist[0][h_i[0]] == min(alldist[0])
True
```

### Using numpy (still computing all n * m distances)

```py
import numpy as np

p = np.array([e.as_tuple() for e in PatientList])
h = np.array([e.as_tuple() for e in HospitalList])

>>> h
array([[ 92,  51],
       [ 90, 100],
       [ 85,  80],
       [  0,  78],
       [ 63,  42]])

alldist = np.linalg.norm(p[:, None] - h, axis=-1)

>>> alldist.shape
(25, 5)

h_i = alldist.argmin(axis=-1)

>>> h_i
array([2, 4, 3, 4, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 4, 2, 4, 4, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4,
       4, 3, 3])
```

#### Using KDTree

```py
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

kd = KDTree(h)

dist, h_i = kd.query(p)

>>> h_i
array([2, 4, 3, 4, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 4, 2, 4, 4, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4,
       4, 3, 3])
```

##### What about more than the closest hospital?

The question adds: "Ideally, we would also be able to rank the hospitals in order of distance, or at least be able to find the second closest, third closest, etc. after the closest hospital is found."

Using `KDTree`, this is also very easy and fast:

```
k = 3  # number of nearest hospitals to find for each patient
dist, h_i = kd.query(p, k=k)

>>> h_i
array([[2, 1, 3],
       [4, 0, 2],
       [3, 4, 2],
       ...
       [4, 0, 2],
       [3, 4, 2],
       [3, 4, 0]])
```

#### Speed

```py
random.seed(0)  # reproducible test
PatientList = [Patient() for _ in range(10_000)]
HospitalList = [Hospital() for _ in range(1_000)]

def closest_py(HospitalList, PatientList):
    alldist = [[h.dist(p) for h in HospitalList] for p in PatientList]
    h_i = [min(range(len(dists)), key=lambda i: dists[i]) for dists in alldist]
    return h_i

def closest_np(HospitalList, PatientList):
    p = np.array([e.as_tuple() for e in PatientList])
    h = np.array([e.as_tuple() for e in HospitalList])
    alldist = np.linalg.norm(p[:, None] - h, axis=-1)
    h_i = alldist.argmin(axis=-1)
    return h_i

def closest_kd(HospitalList, PatientList):
    p = np.array([e.as_tuple() for e in PatientList])
    h = np.array([e.as_tuple() for e in HospitalList])
    kd = KDTree(h)
    dist, h_i = kd.query(p)
    return h_i

%timeit closest_py(HospitalList, PatientList)
2.5 s ± 3.92 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit closest_np(HospitalList, PatientList)
319 ms ± 562 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit closest_kd(HospitalList, PatientList)
7.49 ms ± 15.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

But, most importantly, the KDTree solution will scale in `O(n * log m)` on average for `n` patients and `m` hospitals. This represents huge savings when `m` is large.

##### Large size

Let's get a more realistic problem size:

- 6,200 hospitals (roughly the number of hospitals in the US as of this writing);
- 20 million patients.

```py
n = 20_000_000
m = 6_200

random.seed(0)  # reproducible test
p = np.random.uniform(0, 100, (n, 2))
h = np.random.uniform(0, 100, (m, 2))

# making the tree
kd = KDTree(h)
%timeit KDTree(h)
1.34 ms ± 832 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

# finding the single closest hospital to each patient
%timeit kd.query(p)
9.83 s ± 8.94 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# finding the closest 10 hospitals to each patient
%timeit kd.query(p, k=10)
27.4 s ± 20.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```